# App as Power Platform custom connector

Tags: app

Trying to create a connector for Microsoft's Power Platform in order for others to be able to create Power Apps and Power Automate workflows against Stack* data.

I need a post in order to get write scope access, so, uh, yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required post that isn't really a question doesn't need an answer.